# Is there a way to create a better constraint that would operate similar to foreign key where the foreign key table and column referenced is variable?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a case where I'd like to make a complex constraint check where a foreign key referenced in my table varies based on another value in that table. It might not be the best implementation but I can't change it due to too much tech debt. Currently we don't have a constraint check and this could cause issues and my intention is to fix that and not redo the entire database even if that would be ideal.

Here's an abstraction of my case:

```sql
CREATE TABLE VehicleType (
    vehicletypeid integer primary key,
    vehicletypename varchar not null,
    pktablename varchar,
    pkcolumnname varchar
);
CREATE TABLE Car (carid integer primary key, carname varchar);
CREATE TABLE Truck (truckid integer primary key, truckname varchar);
CREATE TABLE VehicleColourOptions (
    vehicletypeid integer REFERENCES VehicleType(vehicletypeid),
    vehicleid integer,
    colourid integer
); /* colourid would have an fk reference in my use case */
INSERT INTO VehicleType (vehicletypeid, vehicletypename, pktablename, pkcolumnname) VALUES
(1, 'Car', 'Car', 'carid'), (2, 'Truck', 'Truck', 'truckid');
```

There may also be more than two types.

After that my current solution would be to create a function and trigger that will check that the referenced `vehicleid` exists as a primary key in either `Car` or `Truck` dependent on the provided `vehicletypeid`. Those would be somewhat like:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_vehicle_has_pk()
    RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' AS $$
DECLARE
    tablename varchar;
    columnname varchar;
    typename varchar;
    key_count integer;
    vehicleid integer;
BEGIN  
    SELECT pktablename, pkcolumnname, vehicletypename
    INTO tablename, columnname, typename
    FROM VehicleType
    WHERE NEW.vehicletypeid = vehicletypeid;
        
    IF tablename IS NOT NULL AND columnname IS NOT NULL THEN
        vehicleid := NEW.vehicleid;
        EXECUTE format('
            SELECT count(*)
            FROM %s
            WHERE %s.%s = %s;
        ', tablename, tablename, columnname, vehicleid)
        INTO key_count;
        
        IF key_count = 0 THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'referenced vehicle type % does not have corresponding id %', typename, NEW.vehicleid;
            IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
                RETURN NULL;
            ELSE
                RETURN OLD;
            END IF;
        ELSE
            RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;$$;

CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER VehicleColourOptionsInsertOrUpdate
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON VehicleColourOptions
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_vehicle_has_pk();
```

So we have a conditional check during an insert or update in `VehicleColourOptions` to determine if the transaction will continue.

The inverse constraint doesn't exist though, that is, a value can't be created or updated in `VehicleColourOptions` if a corresponding pk doesn't exist in the referenced `VehicleType`s table, however, if a value referred to by `VehicleColourOptions` gets deleted in it's corresponding table there is no corresponding check by default. For instance, the following delete shouldn't be possible but is:

```sql
INSERT INTO Car
(carid, carname)
VALUES
(1, 'big car');

INSERT INTO VehicleColourOptions
(vehicletypeid, vehicleid, colourid)
VALUES
(1, 1, 1);

DELETE FROM Car WHERE carid = 1;
```

The thing I want to figure out is how to implement the inverse constraint, or if a better solution than what I've done exists (assuming I can't change the tables or columns). The solution that comes to mind is to create an inverse delete `CONSTRAINT TRIGGER` on every table that is a vehicle type table. The thing is, I have ~20 tables that reference a "`VehicleType`" and ~50 "`VehicleType`s" each with around a thousand rows that could then be referenced (reminder that this is an abstraction of my actual database). This means if I did it for every table I'd have to do ~20 checks for insert and update (which I'm fine with) but then I'd need to create ~50 delete triggers and each would need to check ~20 tables during a delete. That looks about as follows:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_pk_not_referenced_as_vehicleid()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    AS $$
DECLARE
    oldvehicletypeid integer := TG_ARGV[0]::integer;
    oldvehicleid integer;
    columnname varchar;
    checktables varchar[] := ARRAY['VehicleColourOptions']::varchar[];
    tablewithmatch varchar[] := ARRAY[]::varchar[];
    t_iter varchar;
    ref_count integer;
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
    
    SELECT pkcolumnname
    INTO columnname
    FROM VehicleType
    WHERE VehicleType.vehicletypeid = oldvehicletypeid;
    
    EXECUTE format('SELECT ($1).%s;', columnname)
    USING OLD
    INTO oldvehicleid;
        
    FOREACH t_iter IN ARRAY checktables LOOP
        EXECUTE format('
            SELECT count(*)
            FROM %s
            WHERE vehicletypeid = %s
            AND vehicleid = %s;
        ', t_iter, oldvehicletypeid, oldvehicleid)
        INTO ref_count;
        IF ref_count > 0 THEN
            tablewithmatch := ARRAY_APPEND(tablewithmatch, t_iter);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
        
    IF (SELECT count(*) FROM UNNEST(tablewithmatch)) > 0 THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'vehicletypeid % with vehicleid % cannot be deleted because it is referenced in tables: %', oldvehicletypeid, oldvehicleid, array_to_string(tablewithmatch, ',');
        RETURN OLD;
    ELSE
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
END;$$;

CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER CarUpdateOrDelete
    AFTER UPDATE OR DELETE
    ON Car
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_pk_not_referenced_as_vehicleid(1);
    
CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER TruckUpdateOrDelete
    AFTER UPDATE OR DELETE
    ON Truck
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_pk_not_referenced_as_vehicleid(2);
```

Is there another way to go about this so that I can better replicate an fk constraint for a variable fk relationship?

**Ancillary Question**

Aside from the inability to use an fk constraint, what is a good reason that tables shouldn't be built in this way? I can think of pros, the main one being extensibility so users can associate any type with any type. My above abstraction doesn't do this use case justice because one would likely not have a use case to associate a car and a truck, but in my work the type concept is used for many different things, from vocabularies to locations to objects and we have many different association tables.

There's also the benefit that the back end code can be pretty simple. If I want a UI for users to associate vehicles with colour options, I only have to provide a back end service that will CRUD from the VehicleColourOptions table. If I have a CarColourOptions and TruckColourOptions table this becomes more complex. Not that I'm not willing to put in the work, but that is nice when I'm writing my back end.

Comment: I don't understand your model and what you are trying to do, but are you aware that you can have a rule on your foreign keys? Example: ... foreign key (...) on update <action> on delete <action>. Action can be set null, cascade, restrict and possibly some more, check the documentation for your DBMS

Comment: Don't pour concrete around a bad design. You say you can't fix the real problem because there's too much tech debt, but your tech debt will keep climbing until your development team grids to a halt. The earlier you fix it, the less work it will be: Bite the bullet now and fix it by having *one* table for all vehicles with an extra column for vehicle type. It will take some time, but you'll quickly make that time back due to the productivity gains and reduction in bugs.

Comment: Unfortunately @Bohemian I don't know if we can do a single table. I mentioned in another comment to clarify, but this is just an abstraction of database. These objects aren't related in a way that it's feasible to have one table for them. Each of the tables that can be used as a type have 1000s of rows already. It's like we have Insect, Spaceship and City tables and we call them all Resources. A user may want to assign colour to Insect or Spaceship so now we have a ResourceColour table and have a UI for it. Then we have a need to relate Resources and Country so we have a ResourceCountry table.

Comment: @Bohemian if you think it would better serve someone reading this question I can change the types and names of columns in the abstraction so that it is clear these are not very well related.

Comment: @Lennart-SlavaUkraini, the problem is the way in which I make a reference because the reference is variable based off of the (in the case of my example) VehicleTypeId

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at all sure on what you are about to do, but I guess you are trying to implement some kind of of "sub-typing"? If that is the case a typical pattern is:

```
CREATE TABLE vehicle_type
( vehicletype_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, vehicletype_name VARCHAR(?) NOT NULL 
);

CREATE TABLE vehicle
( vehicle_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY -- could you use a natural identifier such as VIN or licence plate?
, vehicletype_id INT NOT NULL
      REFERENCES vehicle_type (vehicletype_id)
, ...
, CONSTRAINT ak_vehicle UNIQUE (vehicletype_id, vehicle_id)
);

CREATE TABLE car
( vehicle_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, vehicletype_id INT NOT NULL
, ...
, CONSTRAINT fk_vehicle_type FOREIGN KEY (vehicletype_id, vehicle_id)
, CONSTRAINT ck_car CHECK (vehicletype_id = 1) -- assuming car is type 1
);
```

Now, the fk fk_vehicle_type ensures that the car has the same vehicle_type as the parent vehicle, and the check constraint ck_car ensures that only cars can have type car.

Comment: I only made it sub types for purposes of the abstraction. The types are not similar in this way. In reality it wouldn't be Car and Truck that are both VehicleType's, it's more like Spaceship and Ant and they're just ThingType's. There's no good conceptual connection between two different tables and there's a lot of them. However, I do appreciate your suggestion and think it has merit. For example a Thing table with thingid, though I won't be able to modify the tables that already exist to change the pk column. I may be able to add a new column with an fk reference to thingid though.